# git cloned folder is not showing in AWS ec2 CentOS 6 instance

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, centos6

I'm trying to clone a public repo from Github (with the usual `git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git` command) into an AWS EC2 instance running CentOS 6 (after logging in as root of course), so I can deploy it. It says something like

`Initialized empty Git repository in /root/<repo-name>/.git/`

but I tried to access with with `cd <repo-name>` but I get the error message `-bash: cd: <repo-folder>: No such file or directory`. Having used Git for a very long time, this is the first time I have experience this. I couldn't find anything online about this. Not completely a guru in AWS EC 2 server but are the folders hidden for some reasons? This is a weird behavior that I don't normally run into on other systems.

EDIT: here is what I did in the terminal (minus the exact names)

```
[root@AWS-ec2-server ~]# git clone https://github.com/username/repo-name.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/repo-name/.git/
[root@AWS-ec2-server ~]# ls
[root@AWS-ec2-server ~]# pwd
/root
[root@AWS-ec2-server ~]#
```

So where is my repo after I clone?

EDIT2: I was able to get this working after setting up SSH and clone with the SSH url instead of the HTTPS url.

`git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name.git`

I still would like to know why the HTTPS doesn't work for some reasons. Here is some more info requested by Leon.

My git version is 1.7.1

`ls -al /root` outputs to be

```
total 76
dr-xr-x---.  8 root root 4096 Jul 11 07:46 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Jul 11 05:52 ..
-rw-------.  1 root root 5715 Jul 11 07:21 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   18 May 20  2009 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  487 Jul 11 01:28 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  292 Jul 11 01:28 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  100 Sep 23  2004 .cshrc
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jul 11 02:05 .gem
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   19 Jul 11 02:05 .gemrc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   51 Jul 11 02:13 .gitconfig
-rw-------.  1 root root 3239 Jul 11 07:38 github
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  742 Jul 11 07:38 github.pub
drwxr-----.  3 root root 4096 Jul 11 00:36 .pki
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root 4096 Jul 11 02:05 .rbenv
drwx------.  2 root root 4096 Jul 11 06:53 .ssh
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  129 Dec  3  2004 .tcshrc
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jul 11 07:29 test
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root 4096 Jul 11 07:46 texter
```

No output for `env|grep GIT_` as requested

Comment: there is no other input or output I can provide as that is the one I entered and received. If you are on your Mac, for example, and clone a repo, you would normally see your repo/folder cloned, but here I am not seeing anything and those are the output I am receiving. After cloning and try to get the list of the repo with `ls` I don't see the repo name.

Comment: I updated to include what I did

Comment: Does your repository name start with a dot character?

Comment: no it doesn't. If i were to clone it on my mac, i would get a folder `repo-name` but not sure why it's doing this inside the AWS ec2 instance with centOS

Comment: Can you try doing it as a non-root user?

Comment: I tried that, I received the same message as above.

Comment: So, does cloning that repo work normally on your Mac?

Comment: correct. weirdest behavior ever.

Comment: Does your repository name contain whitespace, special symbols or international characters?

Comment: nope. just a one word repo name. nothing special about it.

Comment: Will you please post the output of `git --version` and `ls -al /root`?

Comment: And also the output of `env|grep GIT_`

Comment: I updated my question. I got it to work for SSH urls though. HTTPS not working for some reasons

Comment: Is there anything special in `/root/.gitconfig`?

Comment: no, just my name and email when you set up git config such as `git config --global user.name "...."` and also for `user.email` as well

Comment: Does `wget https://www.google.com` work (it should save a file named `index.html` in the current directory)?

Comment: i don't have `wget` installed. anyway, I found out that this instance of AWS EC2 is acting weird. After starting a new one, `git clone` works fine even when I clone the HTTPS version. I'll marked this as resolved. Thanks for your attempt to help me @Leon!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the current instance of AWS EC2 powered by CentOS is not working correctly. I started a new one and `git clone` works fine without needing to configure SSH to clone it